# href works in Firefox 11.0 but not in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, button, hyperlink, href

I have a link that I want to look like a button so I used the following:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href=/home/index><button type="button">Main Menu</button></a>
```

This works fine in FF 11.0 but does not do anything in IE9, even though the source code shows everything OK. In IE, if I mouse over it, I see nothing. In FF, I do see the link to home/index

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: You are not suppose to wrap buttons with hyperlinks. You could use a <form> and set the action to the link you want to go to.

Comment: Thanks David. Do you have an example for this?

Comment: <form action="home/index">
<button type="button">Main Menu</button>
</form>

Comment: I do suggest you make a <div> though. And have a hyper link inside of it. Look at my real answer below for how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David said, try with a form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/home/index">
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Main Menu"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Gianluca Fabrizi. This solution works fine both in FF and IE

Comment: Just an explanation for others: a button is not an independent object. It must be used with a form otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using the `<button>` element for links and make it a single `<a>` element styled with CSS to resemble a button:

```
<a class="button" href="...">Main Menu</a>
```

Then use CSS to style a.button to look like a button. I usually give it a border, padding, inline-block display style, a :hover effect, and sometimes CSS3 border-radius and gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your href in quotes

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="/home/index"><button type="button">Main Menu</button></a>
```

Comment: Thanks user1030082. That does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do this, if it fits your needs.

```
<div id="button">
<a href="/home/index" style="display:block">Main Menu</a>
</div>
```

This way you can style is much easier.

Comment: Your previous advice with using `<form>` is much better solution.

Comment: Thanks David and duri. The form solution worked better for me because it gives me the button look without any styling or CSS